# Vagrant SSH Tunnel, Node Debug, Automation wont work

Tags: node.js, ssh, vagrant

I have a node server running within a vagrant. The script that starts node 'start.sh' can pick up a debug flag from a file, which I named debug.mode

On the local side I have a script 'startdebug.sh' which logs into vagrant over ssh, writes to the debug.mode file, restarts the script, waits till that is done, then tunnels 5858.

If I run the start.sh file with debug.mode containing '--debug' node opens 5858 and the port is available (I'm checking within vagrant using telnet).

If I do the same using startdebug.sh node says it's opened the debugging port, *however* the 5858 port it unavailable when I try telnet'ing within the VM.

Any idea? :)

### startdebug.sh

```
/usr/bin/vagrant ssh-config > /tmp/vagrant-ssh-config

ssh -F /tmp/vagrant-ssh-config nodejs "cd /var/www/sportsbook-api && echo $mode > debug.mode && export TERM=linux && sudo ./scripts/restart.sh"

sleep 2.5s

ssh -N -F /tmp/vagrant-ssh-config -L 5858:127.0.0.1:5858 nodejs &
```

### start.sh

```
if [ -e "debug.mode" ]; then
    debug=$(cat "debug.mode")
    echo "\nNode $debug mode activated."
fi

nohup node src/main/apps/api & echo $! > run.pid &
```

Comment: Is it possible port 5858 is already busy? Can you check it?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [sf]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Nothing on 5858. The only logic here is node is in a child shell (because of ssh) and can't bind to the port.